# Prompt Text With JTextPane

Tags: jtextfield, jtextpane, jtextcomponent

I am using JtextPane as a JTextField to make use of Html for styling..but I cant implement prompt text functionality..here is my code...

```
    JTextPane txtNm = new JTextPane();
    txtNm.setContentType("text/html");
    txtNm.addFocusListener(new FocusAdapter() {
        @Override
        public void focusGained(FocusEvent arg0) {
            if(txtNm.getText().equals("<html><font face='Tw Cen MT' size='4' color='GRAY'>&nbsp;NAME</font><font color='red'>&nbsp;*</font></html>")){
                txtNm.setText("");
                //System.out.println("in txtnmfocus");
                txtNm.setForeground(Color.decode("#003366"));
            }
        }
        @Override
        public void focusLost(FocusEvent e) {
            if(txtNm.getText().isEmpty()){
                txtNm.setText("<html><font face='Tw Cen MT' size='4' color='GRAY'>&nbsp;NAME</font><font color='red'>&nbsp;*</font></html>");
            }
        }
    });
```

Comment: What is the **prompt text functionality** ?

Comment: Same here. What are you trying to do and what is going wrong ?

Comment: I am trying to do something like that,when the textfld gets focus then it will be empty and when it lost focus then it will set the previous text....

Comment: In the above code in both focus gained and focus lost function the control does not enters the if condition..this is the problem..

Comment: Just print the real value of txtNm.getText() and you will understand the problem...

Answer (score 0):

```
txtNm.getText().isEmpty()
```

Is never empty. For HTMLEditorKit it returns at least `<html><body></body></html>` so is never empty.

Check what is really returned in both cases. You can try to analyse  `txtNm.getDocument().getLength()` checking whether it's empty or not

Answer (score 0):

Text returned by `getText()` should be treated with an HTML parser like [Jsoup](http://jsoup.org/). This is because...

```
"<html><body></body></html>"
```

...and...

```
"<html>
    <body>
    </body>
</html>"
```

...for instance, correspond both to what you would call an "empty string". Though, the string aren't equal to each-other.